# HTML Form Redirect After Submit

Tags: html, forms

This is my form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload-file" method="post"  action="http://example.com/upload">
    <div class="formi">
        <input id="text-link-input" type="text" name="url" class="link_form" value="your link"  onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;"   />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" class="link_but" />
    </div>
    <div class="upl" title="Upload"><img src="http://example.com/example.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>Upload
        <input type="file" name="file" size="1" class="up" onchange = "document.getElementById('text-link-input').value = String(this.value).replace('C:\\fakepath\\','')"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, I want to redirect the submitter to any page of my choice after the form data has been submitted, but the action resides on another website where I cannot edit. Is it possible to redirect the user to any page after he has submitted the data to that site?

From some Googling, this is what I have found. Adding this to form code:

```
onSubmit=window.location='http://google.com'
```

This didnt work. Maybe I didnt implement it correctly? This is what I did:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload-file" method="post" onSubmit=window.location='http://google.com' action="http://example.com/upload">
```

Another person says adding a hidden field should work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://your.host/to/file.html">
```

How should I implement this is my code?

Suggestions and help awaited...

Comment: The hidden field will work when you have control over the form which will process your script, in your case you don't have control so it won't work

Comment: form first hit will go to action   and in action you passes the   http://example.com/upload   and form willl go to that  is that going  to this   url

Comment: @Vickey Yes, it goes to example.com/upload, but I want it to submit data to example.com/upload and then go to some other page. However, I simply cannot edit example.com/upload to add a redirect. Any other way?

Comment: ok   whn you get directed to example.com   add  the redirection code on example.com so it will go to your specified  url   you say that  you unable to edit example.com thas dummy link try to use  your file in your server  which you able to edit   like mail.php and any other name

Comment: Definitely by saying I cannot edit example.com I mean that I cannot edit the Action url, which resides on another website. Basically, I am trying to upload files from a form on my website to another website using their submit php. I know what I am trying can be accomplished with loading the action page in iFrame or by AJAX but I am unsure hoe to do it.

Comment: well, you have to put double quotes (`"`) around an attribute. So not `onSubmit=window...` but `onSubmit="window..."`

Comment: ... and I think its all lowercase: `onsubmit`

Answer (score 34):

Try this Javascript (jquery) code. Its an ajax request to an external URL. Use the callback function to fire any code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(){
    $.post('http://example.com/upload', function() {
      window.location = 'http://google.com';
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: wonder why this got downvoted? looks like the right approach to me (assuming OP is willing to use jQuery). Might need a `return:false;` in that submit handler though...

Comment: This is the first solution I thought of after reading this question. But then saw it is already answered. +1

Comment: If you still want to send the form values too, add something like `$('#form_id').serialize()` as the second parameter to post (after the URL).

Comment: Given the same origin policy, this is unlikely to work for most URLs the OP has no control over.