# A button who submits a form and redirect to another page

Tags: html

I'm currently working on a checkout page for a online store. I was wondering if there are any ways to make a button that submits a form and then redirects the customer to another page?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you try anything..? at least a [google search..?](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+submit+an+html+form+and+redirect+to+another+page+on+button+click&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=TbiqU6qxMaPO8geO74HABA&gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to++redirect+to+another+page+after+submitting+html+form%3F&rls=en&safe=active) :)

Comment: Yes.  `<input type="submit" />` does exactly this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Form Redirect After Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880977/html-form-redirect-after-submit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP, you can redirect the user after handling the submitted data:

```
// After handling submitted data, redirect:
header("Location: new-page-here.php");
```

This is actually recommended, as it stops the user re-submitting the data if they refresh the page.

As per the instructions for `header()`, do not echo any HTML before it. This includes whitespace before your `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
<form name="form1" ACTION="url1.php" METHOD="POST">
    <input type=".."\>
    <input type=".."/>
    <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button> 
</form>
<form name="form2" ACTION="http://www.example.com"></form>
<script>
function submitForm()
{
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    setTimeout('document.form2.submit()',500);
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.