# Redirecting users after they submit a form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a basic form that redirects users to any given web page I choose after they submit their response. Although the action element is located on a site that I can not manipulate.

How would I go about doing this?

```
<form method="POST" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1dAp52ALtiu8tEt8UY-Rs7WcKn36pI1vBItmGl0sV0Ik/formResponse">
<input type="text" name="entry.139518212" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How would one do that?

Comment: Probably by using a JavaScript library (e.g., jQuery) and following any number of tutorials. The issue will be that (a) you're also not in control of how the site *replies* to the post, which may or may not be a problem, and (b) it doesn't sound like you know JavaScript.

Comment: It's fine that I'm not in control of how the site replies to the post, and I'm not very familiar with any client side scripting languages. Could you show me how? I would be appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will need to have jQuery for it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('form').submit(function(){
        $.post('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1dAp52ALtiu8tEt8UY-Rs7WcKn36pI1vBItmGl0sV0Ik/formResponse', function() {
          window.location = 'http://www.whereveryouwanttogo.com';
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

From [HTML Form Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880977/html-form-redirect-after-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax may be helpful for you. you can submit your form through Ajax, get the response and do whatever you want.
you have to create an ajax function and call it on a click event

```
<input id="text" type="text" name="entry.139518212" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sendData();">
```

and then create a js function:

```
function sendData(){
///getting text from input
text=document.getElementById('text').value;
var xmlhttp;
///browser compatibility
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    ///if response was retrieved and no errors occured
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      ///you can access the response
      ///put your redirection code here
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1dAp52ALtiu8tEt8UY-Rs7WcKn36pI1vBItmGl0sV0Ik/formResponse",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("entry.139518212="+text);
}
```