# after submit form,web page redirect to servlet url, but I want redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I am coding on a HTML5 page, which submit a form to a remote web server.

so the in the  tag, I write

```
 <form  action="http://www.myweb.com/serv/addquery.do" onsubmit="redirect()">
```

but everytime after submit, web browser redirect to "http://www.myweb.com/serv/addquery.do"

how to make it redirect to the right page?

```
 function redirect()
  {
    alert(location); 
    window.location="http://www.myweb.com/HTML/RuntimeMonitor.html";
  }
```

I am really new with front coding,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Form Redirect After Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880977/html-form-redirect-after-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

- Change serverside code
- Post form async(**Recommended**).
- Use iframe to post form.

Here is jQuery code with post form async:

```
$.post('http://www.myweb.com/serv/addquery.do', function(){
    window.location="http://www.myweb.com/HTML/RuntimeMonitor.html";
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I make it with your first solution, change the server side code to redirect.

Comment: Great, I also tried the 2nd solution, it works! but why the 2nd solution is better?

Comment: @Sarah Better for UE, the request was posted async, and end user do not feel page reloaded.

Comment: Just a note for others, with some requests, the best option may be using the `iframe`, which works remarkably well.