# How would I post an html form but, still redirect to a thank you page after the form has posted?

Tags: html

```
<form action="http://IneedThisPostedHere.com" method="POST">
    <input name="LidogeneratorId" value="xxx" type="hidden"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="First Name" placeholder="First Name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="City"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="State" placeholder="State"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Zip Code" placeholder="Zip Code"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Telephone Number" placeholder="Phone"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Alt Telephone Number" placeholder="Alt Phone"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="Case Details" placeholder="Conditions that limit your work?"> <br>
    <input name="Referrer GUID" value="xxxxx" type="hidden"> <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the basic form I have here so far. I need the action URL to be posted to but, I need the user to be redirected elsewhere. I have no control over the action url.

Comment: You could use JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/a/17883036/673457

Comment: @Gavin — Ajax is unlikely given the same origin policy. Server side redirection is out of the question since the OP said "I have no control over the action url"

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. I guess that's what I get for not reading the entire question.