# How to return to the same tab after form submit

Tags: jquery, html

How can I return to the same tab after I submit a form? The problem is that after I submit a form it's returning to the default tab instead the last tab that I was in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs").not(":first").hide();

  $(".tab .control a").click(function() {
    storage = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(".tabs").hide();
    $(storage).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#tab1" class="tab">tab1</a>
<a href="#tab2" class="tab">tab2</a>
<a href="#tab3" class="tab">tab3</a>
<a href="#tab4" class="tab">tab4</a>
<a href="#tab5" class="tab">tab5</a>
```

Comment: You could use AJAX

Comment: you could use ajax instead, so there's no refresh. Or you could include the selected tab value as an extra field in the data you send to the server, so that the server can then include that in the data it sends back to the page (e.g. on the querystring), and the page, when it first loads, decides which tab to display based on that.

Comment: @SilverSurfer thanks for your advice, But is this possible to do in jquery?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880977/html-form-redirect-after-submit sounds like what you're looking for

Comment: Sure, if you want use jquery and ajax check this post (assuming you are using php on the server): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: @SilverSurfer AJAX won't help if you want to open `#tab2` when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the fragment to the URL when redirecting from your server response back to the page, eg:

```
/yourpage#tab2
```

You can then retrieve that fragment when the page loads and show the correct tab, something like this:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="tab">tab1</a>
<a href="#tab2" class="tab">tab2</a>  
<a href="#tab3" class="tab">tab3</a> 
<a href="#tab4" class="tab">tab4</a>
<a href="#tab5" class="tab">tab5</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs").not(":first").hide();

  $(".tab .control a").click(function() {
    showTab(this.href);
  });

  var tab = window.location.hash;
  if (tab)
    showTab(tab);
});

function showTab(tabId) {
  $('.tab').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href="' + tabId + '"]').addClass('active');
  $(".tabs").hide();
  $(storage).show();
}
```

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan okay i will try that :)

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan should i replace my jquery code with the one you provide?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan i already replace my code with the one you provided but when i refresh my browser all the content of each tab has gone

Answer (score 0):

You can set your value on localStorage.

```
localStorage.content =$(this).attr("href");
```

After submit get your localStorage value.

```
 if($('a').attr('href') === localStorage.content)
    $(this).trigger();
```

Comment: Note that the second part would need to be done in a loop over all the `a` elements

Comment: @Rory Thanks for comment.